# event data always seems to be null on onWrite

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I can't seem to figure out why the following log only returns an array of null values (like [ null, null, null, null, etc.]

```
exports.scheduleFirst = 
functions.database.ref('savedPlant/{uid}/{pushId}').onWrite(event => {
   const val = event.data.val();
   console.log(val)
})
```

After some further research I found that the '_data'  property of event.data also has 'null' as value. However, the _newData property of event.data contains the newly added data that I'm looking for. So if I do:

```
exports.scheduleFirst = 
functions.database.ref('savedPlant/{uid}/{pushId}').onWrite(event => {
   const val = event.data._newData
   console.log(val)
})
```

It actually returns the object with the data that has been added. What am I missing here?

Comment: Is the data at that location a numeric-indexed array? If so, it sounds like a bug in the firebase-functions SDK and I'd encourage you to [file an issue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions/issues). If not, I'm not sure why you'd be seeing an array...

Comment: @MichaelBleigh I was also having this problem and it is indeed a firebase bug. Even if the key starts with a letter but ends in numbers it does not work